# how to add UIView with code? Without using storyboard

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview

I am a beginner and am only able to add elements via storyboard.

Now I would like to know how to add UIView code to the screen without using a storyboard.

I need to place it at the very top, full width of the screen, replacing the NavigationBar with a UIView

```
import UIKit

class ChatsNavBar: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var statusLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageUser: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var backButton: UIButton! {
        didSet {
            backButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        }
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var navView: UIView!
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    private func commonInit() {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: ChatsNavBar.self)
        bundle.loadNibNamed("ChatsNavBar", owner: self, options: nil)
        navView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(nameLabel)
        addSubview(navView)
        addSubview(statusLabel)
        addSubview(imageUser)
        addSubview(backButton)
        nameLabel.frame = self.bounds
        nameLabel.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    }
    
    @IBAction func backAction(_ sender: Any) {
    }
}
```

```
class ChatsViewController: MessagesViewController {
    
    init(user: MUser, chat: MChat) {
        self.user = user
        self.chat = chat
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)

        title = "\(chat.friendUsername) \(chat.friendUserSurname)"
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        configureMessageInputBar()
        
        let navController = UIView()
```

Comment: While you accepted the answer - I'm assuming because it works - there really are a few things... incomplete about the answer provided by @jawadAli. (It's a decent answer but for a newbie like you, you may run into numerous issues with something more advanced.) First, a navigationController is *much* different than a UIView. The former has a stack of UIViewControllers that push/pop from it, the latter? It's simply a view. Second, I'd recommend learning auto layout instead of using frames. Finally, you probably can simply code against the ChatsViewController default nav bar.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is how you can place it over entire screen

```
   let viewOverLay = ChatsNavBar()
    navigationController.view.addSubview(viewOverLay)
    viewOverLay.frame = navigationController.navigationBar.bounds
```